# Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <403: Forbidden> For Controller Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run a simple test on a Ruby on Rails 6.0 application, but I am getting a 403 error.

```
Alberts-MacBook-Pro:rr albertski$ rails test test/controllers/categories_controller_test.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 72301
Run options: --seed 53214

# Running:

F

Failure:
CategoriesControllerTest#test_should_get_categories_index [/Users/albertski/Sites/rr/test/controllers/categories_controller_test.rb:10]:
Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <403: Forbidden>
```

categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def new

  end

  def show

  end
end
```

categories_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class CategoriesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @category = Category.create(name: "sports")
  end

  test "should get categories index" do
    get categories_path
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def require_user
    if !logged_in?
      flash[:danger] = "You must be logged in to perform this action"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

config/environments/test.rb

```
# The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
# test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
# your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
# and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!

Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'http://localhost:3000'

Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  config.hosts << "localhost:3000"

  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure public file server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{1.hour.to_i}"
  }

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.cache_store = :null_store

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system in a temporary directory.
  config.active_storage.service = :test

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations.
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

I did debug `get categories_path` and it returns `/categories`.  Also, when viewing the `/categories` path in a browser I don't have any issues; it only happens in the test.

Comment: I think you need to sign in before accessing the page. 403 error means its access is forbidden

Comment: please show us `application_controller` class code

Comment: @Vishal the thing is I am able to view the pages not logged in in the browser.

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev I added the `application_controller`.

Comment: Could it be something with the config? I added `test.rb` above.  `get categories_path` returns `/categories` but shouldn't it return `http://localhost:3000/categories`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to find the problem by adding `byebug` to my test, and printing out `response` which pointed me to the following message:

```
Blocked host: www.example.com

To allow requests to www.example.com, add the following to your environment configuration:

config.hosts << "www.example.com"
```

Updating to `config.hosts << "www.example.com"` fixed the problem.

Also, not sure why I had `config.hosts << "localhost:3000"` in there in the first place. Removing that line also fixes the issue.

Comment: Confirmed, after upgrade rails to v6, cause 403 error in tests.

Comment: Where is this change made?

Comment: @John It would be in one of your config/environments files. Most likely test.rb.

Answer (score 1):

Remove/Comment out any `config.hosts << "your-hostname>"` in your `config/application.rb` you may have.

In my case I had my ngrok there.

```
config.hosts << "2f0c5431228v.ngrok.io"
```

Comment: Thank you! For me, I had config.hosts << 'localhost:3000' set in `config/environments/test.rb`... As you suggested, removing it got my tests to work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to run rspec using RAILS_ENV=test

`RAILS_ENV=test rspec`

Rspec will run with your development config if RAILS_ENV is not set, which can cause issues like this.